# Java Error: Class 'Anonymous' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'actionPerformed(ActionEvent)' in 'ActionListener'

Tags: java, actionlistener

I've been struggling to setup an action listener for a button, and I can't figure out why. I've referred to many tutorials, but I've been getting the must be declared abstract or must implement abstract method ..... error. I've seen similar topics about fixing this, but nothing that really helped me out. Any help would be great. Here is a short example that is similar to what I am doing:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Kitty {

    private static void mainFrame() {

        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Kitty");
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainFrame.setSize(200,200);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Pet the kitty");
        mainPanel.add(button1);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        // Line above (Specifically ActionListener) says Class 'Anonymous' must either be declared abstract or
        // implement abstract method 'actionPerformed(ActionEvent)' in 'ActionListener'

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                System.out.println("Purrrrrr....");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mainFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: No mate, an example *similar* to what you are doing won't help. Please past the content you are struggling with, otherwise it is impossible to help you.

Comment: Well, it is pretty much the same thing, but I didn't include the menu bar and item code. This code above actually won't work for me. Is it supposed to?

Comment: @AlessandroSantini i wish more people would take the time to create a minimal example, instead of just copying their whole codebase on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You imported the wrong ActionEvent class. Thtat's why it's saying you didn't implement that method. Use java.awt.event.ActionEvent.

Answer (score 4):

use import java.awt.event.ActionListener instead of import javafx.event.ActionEvent

Answer (score 4):

Import

```
java.awt.event.ActionEvent
```

instead of

```
javafx.event.ActionEvent
```